# blank pdf coming while exporting to pdf in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, ado.net, itext

i have one webform page . i have added everything in one div and wanted to export this div in pdf . while exporting in pdf . pdf is coming with empty.

```
 protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String DownloadFile = String.Format("{0}Targetkeywordsofdt-{1}", ddlproject.SelectedItem.Text, txtEndDate.Text.ToString() + ".pdf");
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + DownloadFile);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        PdfReport.RenderControl(hw);

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);

        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        string strpath = Server.MapPath("~") + "/Temp/" + ddlproject.SelectedItem.Text.Trim() + ".pdf";
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(strpath, FileMode.Create));

        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        pdfDoc.Dispose();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: in text writter everything coming empty
base {System.IO.TextWriter} = {<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PdfReport">
<div style="height:20px" >

</div>
<div>

</div>
                                    <div style="height:50px">
                                    </div>
  



<table>
<tr>
<td>

</td>
<td>
...

Comment: You are using `HTMLWorker`. That class has been abandoned a long time ago because (1.) it was an ad hoc implementation of only a limited set of HTML tags, and (2.) the code was beyond repair. You should use iTextSharp's [XML Worker](http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker) instead.

Comment: Show us your complete HTML and I'll run it to XML Worker to show you what you can expect. For instance, if you have an XHTML file like [this](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/paragj.html), you can achieve a PDF like [this](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/html_table_6.pdf). You'll never get a result like this with `HTMLWorker`. Please read the documentation, so that you can save time, avoiding using the wrong classes.